# Is there a way to search for a page and extract its info with one fetch request from wikipedia api?

Tags: javascript, async-await, wikipedia-api

Im trying to write this function that gets a search string, and returns the first result it gets,
however in said result i get only the page url and some other basic info, no id,no page content.

i would like to get it all as a single json without making a another request.
And that approach also doesnt work ,
since it doesnt seem to be able to find the page even when i send only the title.

is it possible that i can extract the page information somehow without the images and links aswell?

my current function:

```
async function getVideosWikiInfo(term) {
    if (!term) term = 'Nto'
    const searchRes= await fetch(`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&origin=*& action=opensearch&search=${term}&titles&limit=1`).then(res=>res.json())
    const searchUrl= searchRes[3][0]
    const pageTitle=searchUrl.substr(30,searchUrl.length-1)
    console.log(pageTitle);
    const res = await  fetch(`http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&titles=${pageTitle}`)
    console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: Use search (not opensearch) as a generator

Comment: will try thank you, can u elborate why?

Comment: cant manage to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`generator` module](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators) instead of the `titles` parameter, however that means you'll have to use the [search query module](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search) instead of the opensearch api.

The url would be something like

```
`http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query\
&prop=extracts&exintro=\
&generator=search&gsrsearch=${term}&gsrlimit=1\
&format=json`
```

Comment: You should avoid the opensearch API anyway. It's meant for OpenSearch clients (such browsers' search bars) and other clients will not be considered when making breaking changes.